# Like is used as a preposition

Tags: prepositions

> What is the weather **like**?

**My first question**:
After looking up in the dictionary, I found that "like" can be used as a preposition, an adverb, a verb. In the above sentence, I think "like" functioning as a preposition is used to ask somebody’s opinion of somebody/something(http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/like_1?q=like%3F). Am I right?

**My second question:**
I think the word "**like**" in "What is the weather **like**?" and "what is she **like**?" mean the same? Am I right?

Comment: If anyone is curious, there's an [episode](http://www.slate.com/articles/podcasts/lexicon_valley/2015/08/lexicon_valley_the_evolution_of_the_expression_what_is_it_like.html) of Slate's podcast *Lexicon Valley* that discusses the etymology of this usage of "like" (i.e. "What is ___ like?").

Answer (score 2):

Yes, on both counts.  When answering a question like that (see the same use of 'like' there ;-)) literally, substitute the 'what' with the term you desire to use as the simile for the subject of the question.  "the weather is *like* a dream", "she is *like* a gazelle on crack".

BTW, some folks (probably non-native speakers) confuse the form of "What is/was ... like?" with "How is/was ...?" and add 'like' to the end of the 'how' question.  Instead of "Welcome back!  How was the weather?" you hear "Welcome back!  How was the weather like?"

Comment: You could also say "Welcome back! What was the weather like?" and that would be correct

Comment: Yes, that second half is a HUGE pet peeve of mine. The expression is either, "What is _____ like?," or "How is _____." NEVER "How is ____ like?"

Answer (score 0):

I'd *like* to add some other stuff:

> Some uses of *like*:
>   **1.— preposition:** it's used with a noun or a pronoun to describe similarities.
>   Example: *I'm just **like** my dad.*
>
> **2.— conjunction:** also used in informal speech.
>   Example: *You don't study **like** I do.*
>
> **3.— opinion:** share the same thinking.
>   Example: ***Like*** your doctor, I recommend you give up drinking.
>   (I have the same opinion as your doctor.)
>
> **4.— negative clauses:** it can change the meaning if placed before or after a negative clause.
>   Example 1: ***Like*** my dad, I'm not good at tennis.
>   (He's not good and neither am I.)
>
> Example 2: *I'm not keen on action films, **like** my brother.*
>   (My brother likes them but I don't.)

Answer (score 0):

Some have disputed, it seems to me, the formality of the use of *like* as a preposition, but there is certainly no dispute that this word as an adjective or a verb can be properly used in writing; *i.e.*, You and I have a *like* attitude to this subject.

Comment: How does this answer the questions the OP has? Please note that this website, and the platform it is part of, is not a forum. You can take the [Tour] to familiarize yourself with both. Welcome to ELL!